# Slicing data in ipython using pandas datetime

Tags: pandas, ipython

I created a dataframe df2 from RBR.csv and would love to use data only between start:18-04-2015 21:30 and End:18-09-2015 14:09 set to dataframe df3

```
In [12]:

df3 = df2[(df2['date']>=datetime.datetime(18-04-2015 21:30)) & 
          (df2['date'] <= datetime.datetime(18-09-2015 14:09))]

File "<ipython-input-12-95bbb0030f0a>", line 1
    df3 = df2[(df2['date']>=datetime.datetime(18-04-2015 21:30)) &   
(df2['date'] <= datetime.datetime(18-09-2015 14:09))]
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please, format your question properly!
Also, add the sentence with question! ( .... **?** )
Read, how to ask on Stack Overflow (SO) [Link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [Link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Without it, your question would be quickly removed by moderators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the `datetime.datetime` instances properly:

```
df3 = df2[(df2['date'] >= datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 18, 21, 30)) & 
          (df2['date'] <= datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 18, 14, 9))]
```

Alternatively, you can use strings:

```
df3 = df2[(df2['date'] >= '18-04-2015 21:30') & (df2['date'] <= '18-09-2015 14:09')]
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike Müller.